# Bitly Gem/ Oauth Gem issues when starting app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, production-environment, unicorn

I'm trying to deploy my rails application to production however I've hit a bit of a problem. I'm using Nginx and Unicorn and the application has been running fine in production for a while now but a hardware error with my hosting provider earlier today has brought the site down and while trying to revive it the following errors appeared in the unicorn error log:

```
E, [2012-11-23T21:30:03.291386 #4370] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 7795 exit 1> worker=0
I, [2012-11-23T21:30:03.291819 #4370]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2012-11-23T21:30:03.310884 #7801]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=7801
I, [2012-11-23T21:30:03.311488 #7801]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/connection.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- addressable/uri (LoadError)
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/connection.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday.rb:68:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/oauth2-0.5.2/lib/oauth2/client.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/oauth2-0.5.2/lib/oauth2/client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/oauth2-0.5.2/lib/oauth2.rb:2:in `require'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/oauth2-0.5.2/lib/oauth2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bitly-0.7.0/lib/bitly/v3.rb:5:in `require'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bitly-0.7.0/lib/bitly/v3.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bitly-0.7.0/lib/bitly.rb:9:in `require'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bitly-0.7.0/lib/bitly.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/releases/20121123212740/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/releases/20121123212740/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/releases/20121123212740/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from config.ru:4:in `require'
from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from config.ru:1:in `new'
from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:694:in `call'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:694:in `build_app!'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:567:in `init_worker_process'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:587:in `worker_loop'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:487:in `spawn_missing_workers'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:498:in `maintain_worker_count'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:272:in `join'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.2.1/bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
from /home/deployer/apps/stealthygecko/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake'                                                                                                                                                                                                  
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'                                                                                                                                                                                        
gem 'mysql2'                                                                                                                                                                                                
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'                                                                                                                                                                               
gem 'gravtastic'                                                                                                                                                                                            
gem "friendly_id"                                                                                                                                                                                           
gem "videawesome"                                                                                                                                                                                           
gem "will_paginate", "~>3.0.3"                                                                                                                                                                              
gem "bitly"                                                                                                                                                                                                 
gem "sanitize"                                                                                                                                                                                              
gem "newrelic_rpm"                                                                                                                                                                                          
gem 'capistrano'                                                                                                                                                                                            
gem 'rvm-capistrano'                                                                                                                                                                                        
gem "unicorn", "~> 4.2.1"                                                                                                                                                                                   
gem "wysihtml5-rails", "~> 0.0.2"                                                                                                                                                                           
gem 'airbrake'                                                                                                                                                                                              

group :assets do                                                                                                                                                                                            
  gem 'less-rails'                                                                                                                                                                                          
  gem 'jquery-rails'                                                                                                                                                                                        
  gem 'therubyracer'                                                                                                                                                                                        
  gem 'uglifier'                                                                                                                                                                                            
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'                                                                                                                                                                             
end
```

From what I can see its the Bitly gem requiring oauth thats the problem, however I'm not sure how to fix this. if anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `faraday` gem is trying to require `addressable/uri` but that's not in your Gemfile.

Comment: Do I need to add addressable or addressable/uri to the Gemfile? as I tried adding addressable and I still got the same error. If its addressable/uri I need to add how do I do this. And if addressable/uri is required by faraday why isn't it a dependency of Faraday?

Comment: So I've tried adding "gem 'addressable', :require => 'addressable/uri'" to my Gemfile but I am still getting the same error any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

after several hours or deploying and supposedly getting nowhere, it turned out that all I had to do was stop Unicorn completely and start it up again rather than just restart it. its now finding all the necessary dependencies.

The thing that confused me in all this was that I read that Faradays dependency on Addressable had been removed back in August, so naturally I was stumped as to why it was still being referenced.

Thanks for your help Ipwnstuff it was much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, sorry I wasn't there to reply to your comments yesterday.